A simple question about linear dependence on a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$
Let $H$ be a complex vector space and let $x,y\in H$.

Why the condition for $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{C}$ $$\alpha x =\beta y,$$ where $\lvert \alpha \rvert+\lvert \beta \rvert \ne 0$ means that $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent?

I cannot understand what the condition  $\lvert \alpha \rvert+\lvert \beta \rvert \ne 0$ implies. Thanks!

One thing the condition $|\alpha|+|\beta|\ne 0$ implies is that at least one of the two complex numbers $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is nonzero.
If $\alpha$ is nonzero then
$$1 \cdot x + \left(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right) \cdot y = 0
$$
whereas if $\beta$ is nonzero then
$$\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) \cdot x + 1 \cdot y = 0
$$
and so, in either case, $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.
